# Apache Key: Which is it using?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, keys

I'm running an Apache server on Ubuntu.  When I restart it, it asks me for a pass phrase; here's what the dialog looks like:

Apache/2.2.16 mod_ssl/2.2.16 (Pass Phrase Dialog)
Some of your private key files are encrypted for security reasons.
In order to read them you have to provide the pass phrases.

Server 127.0.0.1:443 (RSA)
Enter pass phrase:

I've already worked out how to remove the pass phrase from the key file in question, but I can't find any information anywhere on how to determine which key file Apache is complaining about in the above dialog.  I have dozens of key files on the server in question, although I don't know which ones are in active use (all I did is 'locate .pem' and ignore the false positives).  Does anyone know how to track down which pem file I need to remove the passphrase from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up the server, you should know what keys are being used. Anyway, look out for `SSLCertificateKeyFile` directives. If not contained in the `httpd.conf`, they might hide in auxiliary files included with the `Include` directive.

Comment: I did not set up the server, I inherited it from a coworker who is no longer available, which is why I don't know what keys are being used.  Thanks for the tip.